# SQL: How to query with 2 different criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

I have a boolean column in a table for clothes.
The column is isShirt?
I would like to write a nested Select statement to return:
1) the department name
2) the total number of clothes 
3) the total number of shirts

Expected output:

department, number of shirt, number of clothes altogether
women, 3, 20

I imagine it to look like this:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(clothes_id), something
FROM clothes
WHERE isSHIRT is true;
```

I know it's not going to work but can't think of a solution to achieve what I want.

Any idea how I should execute this? Thanks!

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT department, 
       COUNT(clothes_id), 
       SUM(case when isShirt? then 1 else 0 end) as shirts
FROM clothes
GROUP BY department;
```

Comment: Thanks @vercelli, this works! If I want to count non-shirt, do I change the query to "case when isShirt? then 0 else 1 end)"?

Comment: hope you could help me with a follow up question. I notice that in the CASE WHEN statement, there isn't a condition given i.e. isShirt? = true. Is it because by default, SQL is able to understand that isShirt is a boolean and the return value could either be True or False?

Comment: @dave Yes, no need to equal to true if it's boolean. Please mark it as answered if you would.